# how to remove the rows of a dataframe with -9999 as column value using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
for column in df:
print(column)
print((df[column] == -9999).value_counts()) 
print("")

modelMag_u
False    49977
True        23
Name: modelMag_u, dtype: int64

modelMag_i
False    49985
True        15
Name: modelMag_i, dtype: int64
```

Can anyone please help me how to remove the rows with -9999 as column value?

Comment: Add an example for your dataframe. Do you want to delete a column even if there is one -9999 value in one of the rows?

Comment: post the sample dataframe and expected output

Comment: df[~(df == -9999).any(axis='columns')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:  You want to delete a row if there is any column in that row that has value -9999

```
df[~(df == -9999).any(axis='columns')]
```

How does this work?

`df == -9999` is run first.  This compares every cell to -9999, creating a dataframe of True and False values depending on content of each cell. We then use `.any(axis='columns')`  on this dataframe.  `any` (with the axis=columns parameter) returns True for each row that has `any` true value. This is exactly those rows you want to remove. The `df[~ ... ]` construct keeps any rows that is not True in the ... .  What remains is any row that has no cell with value -9999.

Comment: @Madhan added an explanation.